# Insight-api: Websocket "tx" event - which variables?

Tags: bitcore

the Insight API has a websocket and publishes TX events as described here:
https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api (see bottom of this page)

The documentation says the names are:

> tx: new transaction received from network. This event is published in
>   the 'inv' room. Data will be a app/models/Transaction object. Sample
>   output:

```
{
  "txid":"00c1b1acb310b87085c7deaaeba478cef5dc9519fab87a4d943ecbb39bd5b053",
  "processed":false
  ...                        <------------- ?????????
}
```

There is literally a "..." and I dont know the other names of the websocket!

How do I know the other names execpt txid and processed? There has to be some addresses, value and so on. Where can I find a list of these outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is in the [lib\transactions.js file](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api/blob/master/lib/transactions.js). Line 210 to 215.

```
  var transformed = {
    txid: transaction.txid(),
    valueOut: valueOut / 1e8,
    vout: vout,
    isRBF: isRBF,
  };
```

I took a quick glimpse, vout is an array and isRBS is a boolean.

Honestly, I don't know why "processed" is in the documentation example. I might possibly have overlooked it, or maybe it could be a local produced string.

Comment: Thanks! I think there are more values in tx event. Value "processed" is a working value. I search for values like inputaddresses, outputaddresses, amout of btc and so on. Like every value which belongs to the transaction event.

Comment: I dug deeper now. You can take a look at https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api/blob/master/lib/index.js - line 283 to 289 . That's the transactionEventHandler . Look at the variables assigned to 'var result' , txid, valueOut, vout and isRBF are the only variables. So I can confirm nothing else. The "processed" is probably a dud.